# LINQ Ring: Any() vs Contains() for Huge Collections

Tags: c#, linq, performance, benchmarking

Given a huge collection of objects, is there a performance difference between the the following?

[Collection.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132407.aspx):

```
myCollection.Contains(myElement)
```

[Enumerable.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx):

```
myCollection.Any(currentElement => currentElement == myElement)
```

Comment: A collection of 10'000.000 of int's. winner is the contains for 300%. but it's worthy to consider the variances mentioned below.

Comment: This seems to show a stark contrast between the two: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/State-of-the-UNION.aspx

Answer (score 174, accepted):

`Contains()` is an instance method, and its performance depends largely on the collection itself. For instance, `Contains()` on a `List` is O(n), while `Contains()` on a `HashSet` is O(1).

`Any()` is an extension method, and will simply go through the collection, applying the delegate on every object. It therefore has a complexity of O(n).

`Any()` is more flexible however since you can pass a delegate. `Contains()` can only accept an object.

Comment: `Contains` is also an extension method against `IEnumerable<T>` (although some collections have their own `Contains` instance method too). As you say, `Any` is more flexible than `Contains` because you can pass it a custom predicate, but `Contains` *might* be slightly faster because it doesn't need to perform a delegate invocation for each element.

Comment: Does **Any()** perform the operation on all objects in the collection or does it terminate with the first match?

Comment: At least [according to the source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,8788153112b7ffd0), it stops on the first match. `All()` operates similarly.

Answer (score 15):

It depends on the collection. If you have an ordered collection, then `Contains` might do a smart search (binary, hash, b-tree, etc.), while with `Any() you are basically stuck with enumerating until you find it (assuming LINQ-to-Objects).

Also note that in your example, `Any()` is using the `==` operator which will check for referential equality, while `Contains` will use `IEquatable<T>` or the `Equals()` method, which might be overridden.

Comment: With .Any you can easily compare properties. With .Contains you can just compare objects and you need an extra IEqualityComparer to compare properties.

Comment: @msfanboy:  That's true, but the question was specifically about performance and showed comparing the whole object.   So I don't think that it is relevant here.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose that would depend on the type of `myCollection` is which dictates how `Contains()` is implemented.  If a sorted binary tree for example, it could search smarter.  Also it may take the element's hash into account.  `Any()` on the other hand will enumerate through the collection until the first element that satisfies the condition is found.  There are no optimizations for if the object had a smarter search method.

Answer (score 1):

Contains() is also an extension method which can work fast if you use it in the correct way.
For ex:

`var result = context.Projects.Where(x => lstBizIds.Contains(x.businessId)).Select(x => x.projectId).ToList();`

This will give the query

`SELECT Id
FROM Projects
INNER JOIN (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)) AS Data(Item) ON Projects.UserId = Data.Item`

while Any() on the other hand always iterate through the O(n).

Hope this will work....

Comment: In case you read this; You are conflating LINQ and "Linq To SQL".  And where this discussion mainly centers around `IEnumerable`, your answer is about `IQueryable`.  I didn't review it for correctness, but seems misplaced.