# Are these two linq queries of the same performance? And How to implement .Any in linq query?

Tags: c#, linq

for example, the following composite query + method looks not good enough. I am seeking for better approach.

```
        foreach (var x in A)
        {
            foreach (var y in B)
            {

                if (getLazyList(x, y).Any(z => z == y))
                {
                    blacklist.Add(x);
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
```

Now compared to this one provided by: @Bob Vale

```
 var q = from x in A 
         from y in B
         where getLazyList(x,y).Contains(y)
         select x;
 blacklist.AddRange(q);
```

would 2nd method do the unnecessary loops? in 1st example i use .any() and break to escape the inner loop, how would linq handle this in 2nd case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this;

```
var q = from x in A 
        from y in B
        where getLazyList(x,y).Contains(y)
        select x;
blacklist.AddRange(q);
```

if AddRange doesn't work then just replace the last line with

```
foreach (var x in q) blacklist.Add(x);
```

To handle the break you'd have to use an any clause

```
var q = from x in A
       where B.Any(y=>getLazyList(x,y).Contains(y))
       select x
```

Comment: would it do the unnecessary loops? in my example i use `.any()` and `break` to escape the inner loop, how would linq handle this in ur case?

Comment: @colinfang Yes it would do unessary loops, I didn't notice the break sorry. Contains should be as efficient as any and depending on the collection more efficient in some cases.  Depends if you are only doing an equals comparison.

Comment: yes, i didn't realize the `contain` would do, and the test shows a major improvement after I switch to `contain`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly different LINQ reimplementation of your loops:

`blacklist.AddRange(A.Where(x => B.Any(y => getLazyList(x, y).Any(z => z == y))));`

Comment: Wonderfully efficient solution showing how succinct LINQ can be. Congrats. +1

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loops in the two snippets will perform identically, and the only difference is the use of `Contains` vs `Any`.

This question [LINQ Ring: Any() vs Contains() for Huge Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445219/linq-ring-any-vs-contains-for-huge-collections) discusses the difference between the two operators.

Typically `Contains` should be no slower than `Any`, but will probably execute in the same time.

The difference is that `Contains` will evaluate using the implementation of `Equals`, whereas `Any` accepts a delegate.