# List<MyObject> Contains

Tags: c#, linq

What's the fastest way (coding wise) to check if one entry exist on a list?
MyObject has 2 properties

```
public class Name
{
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

then I have another class like this:

```
public class Foo
{ 
   private  List<Name> Names : new List<Name>();
   public List<Name> Names { get; set; }

   public bool Contains(Name x)
   {
      if (x == null)
         return false;

      >>> Navigate || Equals || Linq.Contains
      >>> What's the easiest way to do this?
   }
}
```

Comment: By fastest way, you mean least CPU usage or easiest to understand code?

Comment: I guess it would be `.Any` [For](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445219/linq-ring-any-vs-contains-for-huge-collections) [details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305092/which-method-performs-better-any-vs-count-0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fastest for List are `O(n)` lookup speed and `O(1)` insert speed:

Atleast One

`Names.Any(n=> x.FirstName == n.FirstName && x.LastName == n.LastName)`

Exactly One:

`Names.Count(n=> x.FirstName == n.FirstName && x.LastName == n.LastName) == 1`

Any() is faster because it short circuits when it finds the first instance of Name.  Count searches through the list everytime to find all instances of Name.

Instead, you could use a **Collection** (e.g. **HashSet**, **Dictionary**, etc) where lookup operations are `O(1)`.  However, collections don't hold the same properties as Lists.  Note, `Hashset<string>` where names are stored as something like `FirstName + (delimeter) + LastName` is faster than any other option you have.

You could also use a **SortedList** where lookup speeds are `O(log(n))`.  However, inserting elements in a sorted list is `O(nlog(n))` because you must keep the list sorted after every insertion.

Answer (score 1):

I would say linq .Any is pretty easy 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx

```
Names.Any(n=> n==x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Linq` should be easier to read. 
Here is sample using `Any`.

```
    public bool Contains(Name x)
    {
        if (x == null)
            return false;

        return this.Names.Any(item => item.FirstName == x.FirstName && item.LastName == x.LastName);
    }
```

**Suggestion:** If the items in your `list` are supposed to be unique then you could use `System.Collections.Generic.HashSet` and use `System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains`..

Answer (score 1):

You might want to compare for the performance with the methods `Contains` and `Any` of the following code:

```
partial class Foo {
    class NameComparer: IComparer<Name> {
        public int Compare(Name x, Name y) {
            return
                object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)
                ||y.LastName==x.LastName&&y.FirstName==x.FirstName?0:~0;
        }

        public static readonly NameComparer Default=new NameComparer();
    }

    public bool Any(Name x) {
        return
            Names.Any(
                y => object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)
                ||y.LastName==x.LastName&&y.FirstName==x.FirstName);
    }

    public bool Contains(Name x) {
        return Names.BinarySearch(x, NameComparer.Default)>~0;
    }
}
```

Comment: My testing reports about 25%~30% faster with `BinarySearch`.