# What is the difference between Contains and Any in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

What is the difference between `Contains` and `Any` in LINQ?

Comment: Not sure why I would get downvoted, perfectly valid question

Comment: I think it's been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445219/linq-ring-any-vs-contains-for-huge-collections

Comment: @msmolcic92 That's a question regarding performance...this is not.

Comment: Documentation is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx

Comment: @Joce Stop it with the strawman. I couldn't find anything on Contains & Any, everything I came across on google was regarding LINQ introductions and tutorials.

Comment: It's all explained right in MS's own documentation. [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx) vs. [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx).

Comment: @Joce Here's the thing.. I could not find that page. Hence the question

Comment: Have an up-vote for your SEO prowess

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`Contains` takes an object, `Any` takes a predicate.

You use `Contains` like this:

```
listOFInts.Contains(1);
```

and `Any` like this:

```
listOfInts.Any(i => i == 1);
listOfInts.Any(i => i % 2 == 0); // Check if any element is an Even Number
```

So if you want to check for a specific condition, use `Any`. If you want to check for the existence of an element, use `Contains`.

MSDN for [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Technically, Contains takes a TSource, which is either a `Struct` or `Object` depending on how the Collection was defined...

Comment: @JJS I meant "object" in the general "everything in C# is an object" sense. Ie, could be an `int`, a `string`, some struct, or a `MyClass`. You are correct of course though

Answer (score 16):

[`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) checks if the sequence **contains** a specified element.

[`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) checks if  element of a sequence **satisfies** a condition.

Consider the following example:

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
bool contains = list.Contains(1); //true

bool condition = list.Any(r => r > 2 && r < 5);
```

Answer (score 7):

**Contains** cares about whether the source collection is an `ICollection`, **Any** does not.

**Enumerable.Contains**
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#f60bab4c5e27a849

```
public static bool Contains<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource value)
{
    ICollection<TSource> collection = source as ICollection<TSource>;
    if (collection != null)
    {
        return collection.Contains(value);
    }
    return source.Contains<TSource>(value, null);
}
```

**Enumerable.Any**
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#6a1af7c3d17845e3

```
public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    foreach (TSource local in source)
    {
        if (predicate(local))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That's not the *only* difference, but it is one I didn't know about!

Answer (score 2):

Another difference as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445219/linq-ring-any-vs-contains-for-huge-collections) is on the performance

- `Contains` is O(n) for a `List` and O(1) for a `HashSet`
- `Any` is simply O(n)

Comment: True, but this question is about the extension method `Enumerable.Contains<T>`, not the interface method `ICollection<T>.Contains`.

Answer (score 0):

[Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Determines whether a sequence contains a specified element by using the default equality comparer.

[Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Determines whether a sequence contains any elements.

As for the documentation:

> Can't seem to find to find any documentation on it.

All (most?) LINQ extension methods: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: That is one overload of Any (and the one that is less commonly used). I would at least include the more commonly used overload in your answer.

Comment: My answer already includes **all** overloads ;) (and all (most?) other LINQ extension methods)