# C# string comparision error

Tags: c#, string-comparison

I am trying to check if value exists in a string array. The below one works but when I tried the next code block, it failed.

```
bool exixts;
string toCheck= "jupiter";

string[] printer = {"jupiter", "neptune", "pangea", "mercury", "sonic"};

if(printer.Contains(toCheck))
{
    exists = true;
}
```

How can I check for trim and case sensitivity?

I tried this

```
bool exixts;
string toCheck= "jupiter   ";

string[] printer = {"jupiter", "neptune", "pangea", "mercury", "sonic"};
 if(printer.Contains(toCheck.Trim(),StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
{
    exists = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can do like this,

```
bool exists = printer.Any(x=> x == toCheck.Trim());
```

Hope helps,

Comment: .Any is better or .contains is better which one is preferable?

Comment: @Kurkula Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23526773/what-is-the-difference-between-contains-and-any-in-linq). In my opinion, Any is better bacause of the comparision.

Comment: will Any do StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase also?

Comment: @Kurkula No, but at comparision you can use ToLower(). Which will convert string's all letters to lower case.

Comment: in this case .toLower() should be used on source and destination value?

Comment: @Kurkula Only `toCheck.Trim().ToLower()` will be enough.

Comment: `Any()` is better and you can replace the `==` with `String.Equals()` to use InvariantCultureIgnoreCase. Using `ToLower()` is an awful idea.

Answer (score 2):

The `IEnumerable<string>.Contains(value, comparer)` expects a compare class instance, not an enum value.

The library does have some ready made comparers available though:

```
//if(printer.Contains(toCheck.Trim(),StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
if (printer.Contains(toCheck.Trim(), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```