# Best way to find if a value is present in the array, and if so execute code

Tags: c#, linq

I'm a student and I was wondering what the most efficient way is to check if a certain value is present in a array.

My second attempt:

```
string value = "pow";
string[] array = new string[] { "pong", "ping", "pow" };
bool valueIsInArray = false;
foreach(var s in array) if (s == value) valueIsInArray = true;
if (valueIsInArray)
{
    // code here
}
```

I've researched and found if I were to use LINQ the code would look like this:

```
string value = "oink"; // value given to the method
string[] array = new string[] { "oink", "oink", "baboinkadoink" };
if (array.Contains(value))
{
    //code here
}
```

**The question is if using LINQ in anyway negatively impacts the speed or consistency of the code, and if there is an even better way to go about doing this?**

Comment: using `LINQ` is just fine... your first method actually quite poor because it will iterate all the items though you have found the matching item. You should at least using `break` for your first method.

Comment: The difference is a question of *microseconds*; put the version which is more *readable*

Comment: As stated I'm just a student at the time, and would like to know if using LINQ does some unnecessary steps that would slow down/cripple the consistency of the code.

And Indeed I guess I could add a "break" upon finding a match.

Comment: If you are doing this once, performance probably doesn't matter. If you are checking lots of things, then use a `HashSet` as it is a constant-time check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Willy-nilly you have to *scan* the `array` up to the *first match* (or entire `array` if there's no match); you can either put `foreach` loop:

```
 bool valueIsInArray = false;

 foreach (var item in array)
   if (item == value) {
     valueIsInArray = true;

     break; 
   }
```

use `for` one:

```
 bool valueIsInArray = false;

 foreach (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
   if (array[i] == value) {
     valueIsInArray = true;

     break; 
   }
```

Try `Array` class:

```
bool valueIsInArray = array.Contains(value);
```

Implement the code with a help of *Linq*:

```
bool valueIsInArray = array.Any(item => item == value);
```

The difference of these methods is a question of *microseconds* (if any); that's why put the version which is the *most readable* for you. My own choice is `array.Contains(value)` - let the system *work for you* and *hide unwanted details* (e.g. `break` in the loop)

Comment: Wow thanks!
Yeah I think I'll just use the contains option; it looks much more readable to me.

Comment: @Dwight VdV: it's you has who is a *master*, and the system should work for you (= check for contains), not you for the system (= scan each item in the `array` if you've found `value` in the process...)

Answer (score 1):

As a commenter said, `LiNQ` won't really trouble you here. The difference is microscopic (even on larger collections). However, if you must use an alternative, use `IndexOf`. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx

Example:

```
string value = "oink"; // value given to the method
string[] array = new string[] { "oink", "oink", "baboinkadoink" };
if (Array.IndexOf(array, value) > -1)
{
    //code here
}
```

Although I'm not sure what `Contains` ends up doing underwater, but they probably make a call to `IndexOf` aswell.

Comment: Yea thanks!
Your example is also a great way I didn't think of yet! :)
I might just use the contains method to make it more readable to me.

Answer (score 1):

Use linq Any(), The enumeration of source is stopped as soon as the result can be determined.

```
string value = "pow";
string[] array = new string[] { "pong", "ping", "pow" };
bool isValuePresent =  array.Any(x => x == value);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Just did [research](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23526773/what-is-the-difference-between-contains-and-any-in-linq) and decided to not use any since it is not needed at this current moment to complicate it to that extent.

I think the contains will be compacter for the time being but I learned anyways so thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You shoud have to iterate through the entire array for checking the value.
Either Linq or Conventional looping methods. Or you can use the

```
Array.Find()
```

also for the same. Better to go with the Linq and make the code is more simpler.

Happy coding