# EF Core how to use linq to match field stores as string but contains items separated by a delimiter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

For example. This table, I want to search items taged with 'c', not with 'c#' or 'c++'. Tags are seperated by a space.

```
ID  |  BookName              |  Tags 

1   |  C++ Primer            | c++ 
2   | .NET Core 3.1 Tutorial | c# .net
3   | Beginner Tutorial      | c c# c++
```

Each book record can be marked with multiple tags, If I use

`dbContext.Book.Where(a => a.Tags.Contains("c")).ToList()`

I'll get all of them. But I only want get *Beginner Tutorial*.
Since I can not use `=` to filter the Tag field. How can I solve this?

PS: I can not change the structure of this table, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first `Split` Tags by whitespace then you can use `Contains` or `Any`

By doing this with `Contains`:

```
var result = dbContext.Book.Where(a => a.Tags.Split(' ').Contains("c"));
```

By doing this with `Any`:

```
var result = dbContext.Book.Where(a => a.Tags.Split(' ').Any(t => t.Equals("c")))
```

These will give you expected result.

You can also check [difference-between-contains-and-any-in-linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23526773/what-is-the-difference-between-contains-and-any-in-linq/23526778)

Comment: wouldn't the contains become == instead, as `c#` contains c, and i don't think it should match on tag c#. aka tags = "php c# f#" should fail where as tags = "php c" should pass.

Answer (score 2):

You could Split the Tags Fields on delimiter (in your case whitespace) and verify if the tag is present. For example

```
var result = dbContext.Book.Where(a => a.Tags.Split(' ').Contains("c"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = dbContext.Book.Where(a => a.Tags.Split(' ').Any(t => t.Equals("c")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by regex too.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^c$| c|c ");
var result = books.Where(a => regex.Match(a.Tags).Success);
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your model as follows :

```
public string Tags
    {
        get
        {
            return TagsList != null
                ? String.Join(" ", TagsList.Select(tag => tag ))
                : null;
        }
        set
        {
            TagsList = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)
                ? value.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList()
                : new List<string>();
        }
    }

[NotMapped]
public List<string> TagsList { get; set; }
```

Then use :

```
dbContext.Books.Where(a=>a.TagsList.Contains("c"));
```