# How to use a LINQ statement to check if a variable already exists for any object in an existing list before adding that object to the list?

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio

I am trying to implement an Add method which adds a car (object) to the fleet (list of objects)(i.e. adds the car to the list of cars).

The car to add should be a parameter of the method, and before adding a car to the list, I should perform check to see if the car exists in the list already using a LINQ statement to check if the registration already exist for any car in the existing list and if the car already exists in the list then I don’t add it.

Below is what I have done so far. If anyone can help, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

```
        public void Add(Car carToAdd)
        {
            var regQuery = Cars.Select(car => new { car.Registration });


            foreach (var car in regQuery)
            {
                if (!regQuery.Contains(Car carToAdd.Registration))
                {
                    Cars.Add(carToAdd);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Reg already exists!");
                }
            }
```

Comment: please reduce your code to a minimum example that shows your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method you can check whether object exist in your list or not, If exist it's first element of a sequence, else return default value in below example it's return null.

You can learn more about `LINQ` from [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

```
public void Add(Car carToAdd)
{
        var qry = (from car in Cars
                   where car.Registration == carToAdd.Registration 
                   select car).FirstOrDefault();

        if(qry == null)
        {
           Cars.Add(carToAdd);
        }
        else 
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Reg already exists!");
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jatin. I still I have a bit of the way to go but this has definitely helped.

Comment: @GavinMcCoy Good to know that, Happy coding !!

Answer (score 1):

```
public void Add(Car carToAdd)
{
    if ( !Cars.Any(c => c.Registration == carToAdd.Registration) )
    {
        Cars.Add(carToAdd);
    }
    else 
    {
        // handle case where car is already in the list
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of answers suggest using `Contains()` method, I would suggest to use `Any()` as it's [more flexible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445219/linq-ring-any-vs-contains-for-huge-collections):

```
if ( !Cars.Any(c => c.Registration == carToAdd.Registration) )
    Cars.Add(carToAdd);
```

You can also use `SingleOrDefault()` to additionaly ensure that Your Cars' list is still satisfying this implicit requirement to have only a single car per registration:

```
var existing = Cars.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Registration == carToAdd.Registration) )

if(existing == null)
    Cars.Add(carToAdd);
```

`SingleOrDefault()` will throw if there are two or more elements satisfying the condition.

Comment: Don't u think u made a blunder in the last if condition in ur code block?I guess there will be duplication!