# Using Enumerable.Contains method for null item checking

Tags: c#, linq, c#-6.0

Let's suppose I have a very simple `IEnumerable` that looks like this:

```cs
IEnumerable<string> foo = new[] { "Apple", null, "Orange" };
```

I would like to check if it contains a `null` item. Based on what I found with Google, I can do this as follows:

```cs
bool containsNull = foo.Any(item => item == null);
```

What about the `Enumerable.Contains` method? The following seems pretty obvious to me, but I've never seen it this way:

```cs
bool containsNull = foo.Contains(null);
```

Is there any problem with the previous expression that results in the `Enumerable.Any` method used instead?

Comment: No, and it should be faster as well

Comment: Please look at this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445219/linq-ring-any-vs-contains-for-huge-collections)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ Ring: Any() vs Contains() for Huge Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445219/linq-ring-any-vs-contains-for-huge-collections)

Comment: I would use Contains for checking if element is in array or not, and would use Any when need to check something more complex, for example, foo.Any(item => item != null && item[0] == 'A' && item.Length == 5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true, in most of the cases `Contains(null)` will do the work. But there is a vulnerability for `ArgumentNullException`. An example can be:

```
string foo = "foo";
bool containsNull = foo.Contains(null); //throws exception
```

In your case, you've already set the generic type as `string` so it is safe to use `Contains`.

Comment: Note that in the case of `string`, `foo.Contains()` looks for a substring while `foo.AsEnumerable().Contains()` looks for a contained char (and won't compile if you pass null).

Answer (score 0):

The "Contains" operator checks whether a specified element exists in the collection or not and returns a boolean.

"Any" checks whether any element satisfy given condition or not? In the following example, Any operation is used to check whether any student is teen ager or not.

In this case is better use "ANY"

yo can to visit https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-quantifier-operators