# Performance of contains method versus where clause on HashSet in C#

Tags: c#, performance, linq

When we call the Contains() method on HashSet, the time it takes is O(1).
Can anyone let me know how much time will be taken by **LINQ Where** clause on HashSet?
Will it same O(1) or it would iterate through all data?

eg...
HashSet hashData = new HashSet(){"a","b","c","d"};

Here, **hashData.Contains()** will take O(1) time.

What about this:?

hashData.Where(c => c.Equals("a"))

Comment: It will iterate all the data, so it will be O(N).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ Ring: Any() vs Contains() for Huge Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445219/linq-ring-any-vs-contains-for-huge-collections)

Comment: The sames as if you used a foreach

Comment: As stated above, `hashData.Where(c => c.Equals("a"))` is O(N) but be aware that it will only be executed if you actually use `foreach` or some other looping construct to loop over the elements of the returned sequence. The call `hashData.Where(c => c.Equals("a"))` on its own is O(1).

Comment: Hash is binary tree so performance is Log2(N).