# How can I compare the variables in my array with the variable entered in the textbox in c#?

Tags: c#

I created an array of mysql data. I want to compare each element of my array with the value entered in the textbox and print the result, but it doesn't work the way I want.Any idea of doing so?

**edit
My goal is to actually make a guessing game, so I created two arrays with Mysql data called answers and questions. And what I want to do is take the value from the user and if it is true, for example my first answer 'fashion' matches the guess the user entered in the textbox, I want the label to write correct and continue with the next answer and try to find the next answer.
**

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        List<string> cevaplar = new List<string>();
        List<string> sorular = new List<string>();
        

        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("Select cevap,soru From soru_cevap", con.cn);

        con.cn.Open();

        MySqlDataReader oku = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (oku.Read())
        {

            var cevap = oku.GetString(0);
            var soru = oku.GetString(1);

            cevaplar.Add(cevap);
            sorular.Add(soru);

        }

        con.cn.Close();

        for(int i=0;i<cevaplar.Count;i++)
        {
            string tahmin = textBox1.Text;
            if (cevaplar.Any(item => item == tahmin))
            {
                label1.Text= "true";
                continue;

            }
            else
            {
                label1.Text = "false";
                break;
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: What is the type of cevaplar[i]?

Comment: `var matches = cevaplar.Contains(tahmin);`

Comment: Its type of string

Comment: The first `false` will negate any `true` results and set the value of the textbox and bail out of the loop

Comment: You have an array you go through but only one label. So your code will always display "false" if there is at least one element that doesn't match. This doesn't fit your description of "compare each element and print the result". So it's unlcear what you actually want. What is the intended result?

Comment: Can you give a sample list of "cevaplar" and the required output for various "tahmin" values?

Comment: I guess you want to `break` if you have found a match not if there is no match. You could initialize a `bool` in the loop to `true` if you have found it. After the loop you check if it's true or false and set the `label1.Text` accordingly. Of course there are easier LINQ ways.

Comment: Answers also have string values, so words are the same as questions, but I haven't used the questions yet.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve your result by using the LINQ method [Any()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0) or [Contains()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=net-5.0) (which will handle the looping for you) like this:

```
string tahmin = textBox1.Text;
// label1.Text = cevaplar.Any(item => item == tahmin) ? "true" : "false"
label1.Text = cevaplar.Contains(tahmin) ? "true" : "false"
```

Notes:

- Don't forget to add `using System.Linq` to the top of your file if you use `Any()`.
- If you want the check to be case-insensitive you can use `Any` with `item.Equals(tahmin, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` instead of `item == tahmin`
- The faster solution will still be `Contains`. But it doesn't allow lambdas, so the point above will not work there.
- Any vs Contains discussion can found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445219/linq-ring-any-vs-contains-for-huge-collections)

Comment: What is the benefit of `Any` vs `Contains`?

Comment: Actually there are differences there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445219/linq-ring-any-vs-contains-for-huge-collections . That was a nice suggestion. Will update the answer.

Comment: I know the differences. I am asking you what the benefit of `Any` vs `Contains` is here. I'll be more explicit - I think your answer could be improved by using `Contains`.

Comment: If you want to check for a specific condition, use Any. If you want to check for the existence of an element, use Contains.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried and it says true when I enter the values ​​in the array, and false when I enter a value other than the array. But what I want is that it should be in order, that the 1st value of the array will be the first answer, the second value should be the second answer.

Comment: I've tried both of them but they don't get in order. do you have an idea?

Comment: `Enumerable.SequenceEqual`.

Comment: but also comparing their length

Comment: Did you try Enumerable.SequenceEqual @naznaz?

Comment: @naznaz, So, you mean you have a few textboxes and labels, and for the textbox0 the answer is the cevaplar[0], for textbox1 it's cevaplar[1],... Did I get it right?